# Установил автопереход на https в админ-панели WP (на сервере без SSL сертификата), теперь не могу войти в панель

Tags: wordpress

Делал восстановление сайта по резервной копии, но это не помогло, как попасть в админ-панель снова?

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A7%D0%90%D0%92%D0%9E/%D0%92%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0_WordPress

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как правильно перенести сайт на WordPress?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-wordpress)

Answer (score 0):

Открой БД в phpMyAdmin или чем ни будь еще и в таблице wp_options найди записи со значениями siteurl и home в поле option_name. Пропиши в этих строках url сайта в поле option_value.

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]